# write a java program to read in a maximum of 100 test grade?

Tags: java

I have to write a java program that reads in a maximum of 100 test grades. I have to calculate mean, standard deviation, highest grade, lowest grade, median, mode, and range! but the catch is i have to read and sort numbers from a file into a array these numbers are 
numbers.dat:43,98,82,57,78,63,88,26,91,76,75,67,49,77,83,72,69,84,65,73,78,89,46,76,66,87,
,22,45,85,92,88,55,89,77,78,67,99,63,68,71,79,82,68,70, these are all the numbers!

so far im having a problem reading through the file and sorting the array,that seems to be my main problem as of now
Here is what i have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Prog7{
   public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{     
      File fin = new File("numbers.dat");
      Scanner input = new Scanner(fin);
      double[] grades = new double[45];
      //read and sort through array
      for(int i = 0; i < grades.length - 1; i++){
      grades[i] = input.nextDouble();
      double currentMin = grades[i];
      int currentMinIndex = i;
      for(int j = i + 1; j < grades.length; j++){
        if(currentMin > grades[j]){
          currentMin = grades[j]; 
          currentMinIndex = j;
           }
         }
      if(currentMinIndex != i){
        grades[currentMindIndex] = grades[i];
        grades[i] = currentMin;
      }
      }//all of my print statements will go here!    

  }//calculate the mean
  public static double mean(double[] grades){
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++){
      sum += grades[i];
    }
    return sum/grades.length;
  }//calculate the median
  public static double median(double[] grades){
    int middle = grades.length/2;
    if(grades.length%2==1){
      return grades[middle];
    }else{
      return(grades[middle-1] + grades[middle])/2.0;
    }
  }//calculate the mode
  public static double mode(double grades){
    int maxValue, maxCount;
    for(int i = 0; i < grades.length; ++i){
      int count = 0;
      for(int j = 0; j < grades.length; ++j){
        if(grades[j] == grades[i]) 
          ++count;
      }
      if(count > maxCount){
        maxCount = count;
        maxValue = grades[i];
      }
    }
    return maxValue;
  }//calculate the range
  public static double range(double[] grades){
    double intMin = grades[0];
    double intMax = grades[0];
    for(int i =1; i < grades.length; i++){
      if(grades[i] < intMin){
        intMin = grades[i];
        if(grades[i] > intMax)
          intMax = grades[i];
      }
      return intMax-intMin;
    }
  }//calculate the Standard Deviation
  public static double standardDeviation(double[] grades){
    double deviation = 0.0;
    if((grades != null) && (grades.length > 1)){
      double mean = mean(grades);
      for(double value: grades){
        double delta = value - mean;
      deviation += delta * delta;
    }
    deviation = Math.sqrt(deviation/grades.length);
    }
    return deviation;
  }

}
```

Comment: so, what's your question?

Comment: Why do you initialize the array with a size of 45 when you want to read 100 values?

Comment: "so far im having a problem reading through the file and sorting the array" - please be more specific.  What trouble are you having with reading the file?  What trouble are you having with sorting the array?

Comment: "so far im having a problem reading through the file and sorting the array" -- what sort of a problem? Compile error? Crash? Incorrect output? Give us something to work with here.

Comment: @qqilihq Problem says a maximum of 100 - might mean up to 100 grades can be entered.  45 seems to be a specific test case.

Comment: I think reading the file and sorting the array is the bulk of your assignment. What I'd your specific problem?

Comment: Don't use `double` when grades are integers. - For sorting, `java.util.Arrays.sort` is all you need: `sort(grades);`.

Answer (score 1):

Read in your whole file with a bufferedReader

`BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));`

Then iterate through the numbers, adding them to a list

```
List<Integer> grades = new ArrayList<>();
while(br.hasNextInt()){
    grades.add(br.nextInt());
}
```

Then sort your array

`Collections.sort(grades);`

from there, you can calculate anything you want!

mean:

```
int total =0;
for(int i : grades){
    total+=i;
}
mean = total/grades.size();
```

median:

```
median = grades.get(grades.size()/2);
```

etc...

Comment: And HW assignment is done.

Comment: dude, really? :D This guy should learn by himself.

Comment: If they are using this for a homework and the class has not taught how to read a file yet, I think this will stick out pretty well. How they use it is up to them, but I tried to explain each step, rather than dictate.